# Convert csv file to txt file

Tags: python, bash, perl, csv

I'm using perl to convert a comma separated file to a tab separated file with this command:

```
perl -e ' $sep=","; while(<>) { s/\Q$sep\E/\t/g; print $_; } warn "Changed $sep to tab on $. lines\n" ' csvfile.csv > tabfile.tab
```

However, my file has additional commas that I do not want to be separated in specific columns. Here's and example of my file:

```
ADNP, "descript1, descript2", 1
PTB, "descriptA, descriptB", 5
```

I only want to convert the comma's outside of the quotations to tabs as so:

```
ADNP    descript1, descript2    1
PTB    descriptA, descriptB    5
```

Is there anyway to go about doing this with either perl, python, or bash?

Comment: http://perlmaven.com/how-to-read-a-csv-file-using-perl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trivial in Perl, using `Text::CSV`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

#configure our read format using the default separator of ","
my $input_csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1 } );
#configure our output format with a tab as separator. 
my $output_csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1, sep_char => "\t", eol => "\n" } );

#open input file
open my $input_fh, '<', "sample.csv" or die $!;
#iterate input file - reading in 'comma separated' 
#printing out (to stdout -can use filehandle) tab separated. 
while ( my $row = $input_csv->getline($input_fh) ) {
    $output_csv->print( \*STDOUT, $row );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In python

```
import csv

with open('input', 'rb') as inf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    with open('output', 'wb') as out:
        writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter='\t')
        writer.writerows(reader)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need regular expressions to help you. In python it would simply be:

```
>>> re.split(r'(?!\B"[^"]*),(?![^"]*"\B)',  'ADNP, "descript1, descript2", 1'
['ADNP', ' "descript1, descript2"', ' 1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off rll's regex answer, you can turn it into a perl oneliner like you're currenly doing

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$,="\t";}@a=split(/(?!\B"[^"]*),(?![^"]*"\B)/);print @a' csvfile.csv > tabfile.tab
```

Answer (score 0):

This'll work:

```
perl -e '$sep=","; while(<STDIN>) { @data = split(/(\Q$sep\E?\s*"[^"]+"\s*\Q$sep\E?)/); foreach(@data){if(/"/){s/^\Q$sep\E\s*"//;s/"\s*\Q$sep\E$//;}else{s/\Q$sep\E/\t/g;}}print(join("\t",@data));} warn "Changed $sep to tab on $. lines\n"' < csvfile.csv > tabfile.tab
```

Putting parens in the pattern to split, returns the captured separators along with the split elements and effectively separates the strings containing quotes into separate list elements that can be treated differently when quotes are detected. You just strip off the commas and quotes for the quoted strings and substitute for tabs in the other elements, then join the elements with tabs (so that the quoted strings get joined with tabs to the other already tabbed strings.

Comment: Not as efficient as @cts's answer since it uses a foreach loop, but it does remove the quotes. Another version on this theme: `perl -e '$sep=",";while(<STDIN>){print(join("\t",map {if(/"/){s/^\Q$sep\E\s*"//;s/"\s*\Q$sep\E$//;}else{s/\Q$sep\E/\t/g;}$_} split(/(\Q$sep\E?\s*"[^"]+"\s*\Q$sep\E?)/)));} warn "Changed $sep to tab on $. lines\n"' < csvfile.csv > tabfile.tab`

Answer (score 0):

The [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) module is what you're looking for. There are a lot of considerations when parsing CSV files, and you really don't want to handle all of them yourself.